# No Error No Data store into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

When running this code not getting any error, but even no data store into database. All database connections valid. Please help to solve this mystery. Database structure also having 17 fields i checked with proper data type.

**Form Page Coding**

```
<?php include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$purchase_date=$_POST['purchase_date'];
$assession_no=$_POST['assession_no'];
$book_title=$_POST['book_title'];
$edition=$_POST['edition'];
$publisher=$_POST['publisher'];
$year_of_publish=$_POST['year_of_publish'];
$volume=$_POST['volume'];
$number_of_pages=$_POST['number_of_pages'];
$source=$_POST['source'];
$cost=$_POST['cost'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$note=$_POST['note'];
$category=$_POST['category'];   

$sql=mysql_query("insert into add_book(b_id,purchase_date,assession_no,book_title,edition,publisher,year_of_publish,volume,number_of_pages,source,cost,quantity,note,category) values('','$purchase_date','$assession_no','$book_title','$edition','$publisher','$year_of_publish','$volume','$number_of_pages','$source','$cost','$quantity','$note','$category')");

} ?>

     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=""  class="basic-grey" >
     <label>
        <span>Purchase Date:</span>
        <input name="purchase_date" type="text" class="datepicker" id="popup_container" required/>
    </label>
     <label>
        <span>Assession No. :</span>
        <input name="assession_no" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Book Title :</span>
        <input  type="text" name="book_title" id="title" placeholder="" value="" required/>

    </label>
     <label>
        <span>Edition :</span>
        <input name="edition" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

     <label>
        <span>Publisher :</span>
        <input name="publisher" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

   <label>
        <span>Year of Publish:</span>
        <input type="text"  name="year_of_publish" value="" required/>
    </label>

         <label>
        <span>Volume:</span>
        <input name="volume" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Page:</span>
        <input name="number_of_pages" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Source:</span>
        <input name="source" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Cost:</span>
        <input name="cost" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

      <label>
        <span>Quantity :</span>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>General Note :</span>
        <textarea id="message" name="note" placeholder="" value=""></textarea>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>Category :</span><select name="category" required>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="General">General</option>
        <option value="Competitive">Competitive</option>
        <option value="Reading Space">Reading Space</option>
        </select>
    </label> 


                                                    <label>Image Upload</label>
                                                    <input type="file"  name="photo" /></span>
                                                                <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>                                                       





     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" /> 
    </label>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Config.php Coding**

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") ;
$db=mysql_select_db("friendslib",$con) ; 
?>
```

Comment: echo your query and run it manually on db `insert into add_book(b_id,purchase_date,assession_no,book_title,edition,publisher,year_of_publish,volume,number_of_pages,source,cost,quantity,note,category) values('','$purchase_date','$assession_no','$book_title','$edition','$publisher','$year_of_publish','$volume','$number_of_pages','$source','$cost','$quantity','$note','$category'`

Comment: how do you excpect to get an error without error reporting enabled?

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql

Answer (score 1):

put this on the top of the page
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

and set form type to post and 
$sql=mysql_query(" YOur code") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

you are not handling any error! how do you know you are not getting any error?

put this at the top of your page:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

EXTRA NOTE:

do not use mysql functions. you need to use mysqli or PDO.

use this code:

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into add_book(purchase_date,assession_no,book_title,edition,publisher,year_of_publish,volume,number_of_pages,source,cost,quantity,note,category) values('$purchase_date','$assession_no','$book_title','$edition','$publisher','$year_of_publish','$volume','$number_of_pages','$source','$cost','$quantity','$note','$category')");

}
```

Note:

I see that you have `b_id` in your query `but you are leaving it empty in the values`! so i fixed that. i hope it helps.

**second edit:**

it the error that you've posted, it shows `mysqli` error but you are using `mysql`! you cannot use `mysqli` with `mysql`.

can you please make sure that you either use mysqli or mysql in both config.php and your other_php_page.php ?

Comment: Now Getting this error: "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\School Management\Untitled-1.php on line 21
"

Comment: @SmritiTechnoLogics, i edited my answer based on your error. please replace that part of your code with the one I posted in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error:

```
<form action=""  class="basic-grey" >
```

Change it to:

```
<form action=""  class="basic-grey" method="post">
```

[Default form method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) is `get`, if you do not set it, it assumes it to be `get`.

You are checking `$_POST['submit']` which will never set due to this.

**NOTE:**

do not use mysql functions, they are deprecated and will be removed in the next version of PHP. you need to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @programming Student not working even after using post method.

Comment: Print SQL and paste it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you don't handling any thing must fill action and method like this :

```
<form action="NAME OF THIS PAGE like page.php" method="post" >
</form>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Error is Solved using following codes:

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "friendslib") ;
error_reporting(-1);

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$purchase_date=$_POST['purchase_date'];
$assession_no=$_POST['assession_no'];
$book_title=$_POST['book_title'];
$edition=$_POST['edition'];
$publisher=$_POST['publisher'];
$year_of_publish=$_POST['year_of_publish'];
$volume=$_POST['volume'];
$number_of_pages=$_POST['number_of_pages'];
$source=$_POST['source'];
$cost=$_POST['cost'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$note=$_POST['note'];
$category=$_POST['category'];   

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"insert into add_book(purchase_date,assession_no,book_title,edition,publisher,year_of_publish,volume,number_of_pages,source,cost,quantity,note,category) values('$purchase_date','$assession_no','$book_title','$edition','$publisher','$year_of_publish','$volume','$number_of_pages','$source','$cost','$quantity','$note','$category')");

} ?>

     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=""  class="basic-grey" method="post" >
     <label>
        <span>Purchase Date:</span>
        <input name="purchase_date" type="text" class="datepicker" id="popup_container" required/>
    </label>
     <label>
        <span>Assession No. :</span>
        <input name="assession_no" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Book Title :</span>
        <input  type="text" name="book_title" id="title" placeholder="" value="" required/>

    </label>
     <label>
        <span>Edition :</span>
        <input name="edition" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

     <label>
        <span>Publisher :</span>
        <input name="publisher" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

   <label>
        <span>Year of Publish:</span>
        <input type="text"  name="year_of_publish" value="" required/>
    </label>

         <label>
        <span>Volume:</span>
        <input name="volume" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Page:</span>
        <input name="number_of_pages" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Source:</span>
        <input name="source" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Cost:</span>
        <input name="cost" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

      <label>
        <span>Quantity :</span>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="" required/>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>General Note :</span>
        <textarea id="message" name="note" placeholder="" value=""></textarea>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>Category :</span><select name="category" required>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="General">General</option>
        <option value="Competitive">Competitive</option>
        <option value="Reading Space">Reading Space</option>
        </select>
    </label> 


                                                    <label>Image Upload</label>
                                                    <input type="file"  name="photo" /></span>
                                                                <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>                                                       





     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" /> 
    </label>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the $sql=mysqli_query in your original code? you've created a confusion for everyone by posting a different code in your question!!!

Comment: @user3806613 No I was not did any confusion, actually after help of all of you..I make changes in original code and posted again above. thats it. Even thankful to all of yours for helping me in this.

Comment: you need to update your original code in your question as and when you make changes to it so others can see what you've done so they can help accordingly. as i said, in your original code you've used mysql but in the answer you've posted, you've used mysqli and at no point you've mentioned that you've made that change in your original code and that created confusion. Good luck